# Pydantic - Allow missing field

Tags: pydantic

I have a pydantic model. One of its fields must be supplied by user, however, the second one can be present but it is totally okay if it is missing.

In case of missing `age`, I don't want it to be present on pydantic model instance at all.

**My Model:**

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Employee(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: Optional[int]
```

**Problem:**

```py
e = Employee(name="Harwey Smith")
e.age  # Has age parameter equal to None, even if not provided.
```

How do I setup my Employee pydantic model not to have `age` attribute at all if it is not provided on init? If I would try to access `e.nonexistent` attribute, `AttributeError` would be thrown. This is what I want to happen for `e.age`, if not provided.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The validation does not fail and an `Employee` can be created successfully with Pydantic 1.9.1.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Sorry, I just edited question to be more understandable. My fault.

Comment: In pydantic V2 you'll be able to use a TypedDict which supports this functionality. It's not possible pydantic v1.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, your case is rather unusual and I would always prefer to have a field with a `None` value. I think it is simpler and receiving an `AttributeError` is something unexpected if we consider the type hint that any IDE would show for `age`. Having said that, what you want is possible if you use a [`@rootvalidator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) to remove the `age` field:

```python
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Employee(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: Optional[int]

    @root_validator(skip_on_failure=True)
    def _remove_age_if_none(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        if "age" in values and values["age"] is None:
            del values["age"]
        return values


e = Employee(name="Harwey Smith")
print(e.age)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'age'
```

This approach is something I haven't seen in the Pydantic documentation, but I have seen some answers that show that a `@rootvalidator` can be used to delete a field. In my opinion this behavior is odd and I would not be surprised if it is changed in future releases of Pydantic. Be careful.